# I am migrating my web api to .net core.The get methods are working fine but login method is not getting called

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

**Login api in account controller which is not getting called**

```
   //  [HttpPost]
  //  [AllowAnonymous]
    //   [Route("UserLogin")]
    [HttpPost("UserLogin")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UserLogin([FromBody] UserLoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && model != null)
        {
            //var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Usr, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            UserLoginInfo aa = new UserLoginInfo(model.UserName, model.Password,model.UserName);
          //  var result = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            var isVerified = context.UserMappings
                .Any(x => x.IsVerified == true && x.IsActive == true
                && x.UserName == model.UserName);
            var ticket = new Ticket();
```

**Angularjs frontside code**

```
       var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:19989/api/';


       var login = function (item) {
            return $http({
                method: 'Post',
                url: baseUrl + 'Account/UserLogin',
                data: item
            });
        };
  $scope.login = function (form) {
          form.$setValidity('valid', true);
            if (form.$invalid) {
              return;
            }
    authService.login($scope.LoginData).success(function (data, status, headers)         {
         if (data && !data.hasOwnProperty('Message')) {
```

**Get api that is working fine**

```
 [Route("api/Containers")]
        public ResultSet<ContainerModel> GetContainers([FromUri] Container filter = null)
        {
            var resultCount = GetContainerQuery(filter).Count();

            // var resultCount = db.Containers.AsNoTracking().Include("Fridge").Include("Fridge.Department").Include("Units").Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).Count();
            var result = GetContainerQuery(filter);
```

**Applicationdbcontext file**

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)//, throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
            //Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            //Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>());
            //Database.Initialize(true);
        }
```

When I am trying to login to my application the login method is not getting called. It goes into the application db context file and from there it comes directly outside and internal server error occurs.
Whereas in case of get api which i have shown are getting called when i checked it in postman
The methods in my account controller are not getting called. what should i do?

Comment: Got the answer. I had used  ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat in account controller constructor which was creating an error and hence my account controller was not getting accessed.